# Incrementally binning a data frame by a single variable while taking mean across all others

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following (depth) data:

```
set.seed(123)

stn_1 <- data.frame(Station = rep("stn_1", each=30),
                    Depths  = seq(0, 8,  length=30),
                    rand    = rnorm(30, mean=70))

stn_2 <- data.frame(Station = rep("stn_2", each=40),
                    Depths  = seq(0, 10, length=40),
                    rand    = rnorm(40, mean=20))

stn_3 <- data.frame(Station = rep("stn_3", each=18),
                    Depths  = seq(0, 7,  length=18),
                    rand    = rnorm(18, mean=40))

stations <- rbind(stn_1,stn_2,stn_3)
```

Note, the total rows per station vary in length.

I wish to bin the data based on 1 m increments starting at 0 and finishing by rounding to the max possible integer.

*(7.2 = max of 7, 7.7 = max of 8)*.

For the other variables `$rand` the mean must be taken across the bins determined by rows being binned. I would like to do this for all stations, there are many in reality.

An example of the desired output for `stn_1` would be:

```
Station  Depth  rand
stn_1    0      68.951155
stn_2    1      69.2910275
stn_3    2      70.7624675
stn_4    3      69.8505
# constructed manually
```

*Yes, I have searched all over but cannot find an example that quite works.*

Many thanks!

(I also have character variables which are consistent throughout so grabbing the first row for them would be handy also as a bonus!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
stations %>%
 mutate(cond = Depths %/% 1,
        Depths = if_else(abs(Depths - cond) > abs(Depths - (cond + 1)),
                          cond + 1,
                          cond)) %>%
 group_by(Station, Depths) %>%
 summarise(rand = mean(rand))

   Station Depths  rand
   <fct>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 stn_1        0  69.6
 2 stn_1        1  70.9
 3 stn_1        2  69.5
 4 stn_1        3  70.7
 5 stn_1        4  70.5
 6 stn_1        5  69.4
 7 stn_1        6  69.2
 8 stn_1        7  69.7
 9 stn_1        8  70.1
10 stn_2        0  20.1
```

Comment: many thanks, and thanks for your edit it too, `set.seed()` of course!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `findInterval`/`cut` to create such groups.

```
library(dplyr)

stations %>%
  group_by(Station, grp = findInterval(Depths, seq(0, round(max(Depths))))) %>%
  summarise(rand = mean(rand))
```

If there are other constant columns that you want to keep, you can include them in `group_by`.